# Generate new slide layout from old slide layout

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I want to generate a new slide, using the same layout as an old slide but the content of the new one.

Slide 1
Slide 2

I need Slide 2 to change its design to Slide 1's design while keeping it txt content. I managed to copy exact slides with the code below, but it is not perfect and overwrites everything.

```
def copy_external(external, new):

    # copy from external presentation all objects into the existing presentation
    external_pres = external

    # specify the slide you want to copy the contents from
    ext_slide = external_pres.slides[1]

    # Define the layout you want to use from your generated pptx
    # slide_layout = new.slide_layouts[0]
    # lay = external.slide_layouts.index()
    # lay = external.slide_layouts.get_by_name()
    slide_layout = new.slide_layouts[6]

    # create now slide, to copy contents to
    curr_slide = new.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)

    # now copy contents from external slide, but do not copy slide properties
    # e.g. slide layouts, etc., because these would produce errors, as diplicate
    # entries might be generated

    for shp in ext_slide.shapes:
        el = shp.element
        newel = copy.deepcopy(el)
        curr_slide.shapes._spTree.insert_element_before(newel, 'p:extLst')
        #curr_slide.SlideShapes.add_shape(new_shape)

    return new.save('test1.pptx')
```

Comment: Do both presentations contain the same slidemaster layouts? If so, it seems you should maybe be able to just update the layout, but I haven't tried. If not, can you elaborate on the specifics of "it's not perfect" and "it overwrites everything"?  There's actually an open issue about slide portability/ability to copy from one presentation to another. This was not part of the original scope of the `pptx` library though.

Comment: https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/132